# What does "program &" mean on the command line?

Tags: shell, unix

I need to develop a client and server program with using sockets. My program should get port number from the command line. I saw an example which says "myprogram 2454 &".

I wonder what that `&` (ampersand) means there.

Comment: See `man bash` (or the appropriate man/ual).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line

Answer (score 1):

It means to start the process in the background. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html so that you may continue to use your shell session to run other programs. You can then use `fg` to "foreground" your process again.

Comment: The ABS is to bash what w3schools is to JavaScript -- an outdated resource full of buggy examples, but with lots of Google juice. The Wooledge wiki is a better resource -- see its [ProcessManagement](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_run_a_job_in_the_background.3F) page -- as is the bash-hackers wiki, which covers the relevant syntax at [Basic grammar rules of Bash / Lists](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar?s[]=background#lists)

Answer (score 0):

The  ampersand  (`&`)  means that you want to run `myprogram` in background.  This is normally used when you want to stay on your command-prompt and continue the work on the same session.

Example

```
somescript  &
```

will run the `somescript` shell script  in background.  You will get the prompt back on the next line.  If you run `somescript` without `&` then the prompt may not appear back because `somescript` may take more time.

The best way is to run it in background with no hangups, in which case even of you loose your connection to the host the process keeps running on the UNIX or Linux host.

For example

```
nohup  somescript &
```

the  jobs command will  display  the jobs running in background.

Comment: As a note -- I personally wouldn't recommend `nohup` here: Everything that `nohup` does can be done directly from bash, either by using the `trap` builtin to specify that the `HUP` signal should be ignored, or detaching from the TTY by redirecting stdin from `/dev/null` or stdout and stderr to a file.